# Specify the view in layout and hide initially

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I created three views `ViewA,ViewB,ViewC` and added the in to the layout. Two views, `ViewA and ViewC` should be  visisble when the application is started and another `viewB` should be visible only when I click a button on the toolbar.The positions for the `ViewA` will be in the left side, and `View B` in the editor side and `View C` is below to the editor.It is similar to javaexplorerview,editorarea and down console area.so Initially the editor area will be empty and when we double click the java file it will be opened. Such view layout I need.Where should i write the code for hiding the view initially? If I don’t add the ViewB folderLayout.addView("ViewB"); then layout is not coming as I mentioned above.

```java
@Override
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {   

        layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
        layout.addView("ViewA", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.12f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);       
        IFolderLayout folderLayout = layout.createFolder("folder",
                IPageLayout.TOP, 0.11f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
        folderLayout.addPlaceholder("ViewB" + ":*");

        folderLayout.addView("ViewB");

        layout.addView("ViewC", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.56f, "ViewC")

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think he wants to have `ViewB` and the views from `ViewB:*` in the same folder

If so replace

```
folderLayout.addView("ViewB");
```

with

```
folderLayout.addPlaceholder("ViewB");
```

`ViewB` wont be visible initially.
thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Use another `IFolderLayout` for the area containing ViewB and add the placeholder for ViewB to that layout.